# SQL Server CE 4.0 Embeded Deployment Issues

Tags: sql-server, winforms

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I am developing an application where I am using SQL Server CE as an imbedded database.  To do so, I put the “7 Dlls” that comprise the CE edition in the same folder as the EXE file along with System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll and then in code registered the COM objects.  Wow, I was so pleased because everything worked. Being careful, I wanted to confirm all was well and uninstalled the SQL Server CE that I used for development.  Fine!  The app still worked.  Going a step further I removed the 7 Dlls, leaving only System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll.  I expected then to see that the application crashed.  I was astonished because the application still worked.  I then did a Windows folder search of my entire computer to find the 7 Dlls.  The search found nothing, so I’m puzzled as to why.
I do have a local installation of SQL Server 19 on my computer.  Is it possible the app is using some of the files in SQL Server 19?  I’m at the end of my wits.

I have tried to find another app trhat uses CE and have searched for files that may have been installed.  I also did a registry search and found nothing.

My goal is to deploy this Windows desktop program with confidence it will function properly.

Thanks for any help with my problem.

Comment: SQL Server CE hasn't been supported for years; extended support ended in 2021. If you're currently developing your application and not maintaining an existing one, I'd strongly suggest not using it in favor of something like LocalDB or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I'm old school and haven't kept up with the changes.  I heed your advice and check out these tools.